# What is the bond energy of H-O? Wikipedia disagrees with itself

Tags: physical-chemistry, enthalpy

What is the bond energy of H-O? Wikipedia disagrees with itself:

- On [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_bond):
  467 kJ/mol
- On [French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_chimique):
  366 kJ/mol

What is the right value?

Comment: Look, both links are Wikipedia pages containing a table each. The table headers have superscript numbers seven $(^7$ and $^{[7]}),$ which refer to the entries from the list of references on the bottom of each page. These are the sources you should compare, not Wikipedia pages.

Comment: Sure, but for the french wikipedia, the link is broken, so I could not compare. For english wikipedia, the link is given the same as information in english wikipedia.

Comment: Then I'd prefer English Wikipedia — at least you can look up the source of information. Also, it's closer to the accepted value.

Comment: Plus 1,not really for the question that perhaps is a bit naive, but for having spotted the difference. I think this link should clarify why the pages show different values. Out of calculation, one should identify what O-H bond mean. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy

Comment: thank you. Apparently, there are *several* values, depending on the environnement : O−H  in water  497
O−H  in methanol  440

Comment: I think generally it's a prudent recommendation to avoid Wikipedia as a reference for precise scientific values.  The CRC handbook is a gold standard for a reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the 97th edition of the *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics*, table 1 *Bond Dissociation Energies in Diatomic Molecules* [1, p. 9-76]:

$$D^\circ_{298}(\ce{H-O}) = \pu{(429.74\pm 0.03) kJ mol-1}.$$

The value has been taken from the article by Ruscic et al. [[2](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00214-013-1415-z)]. Note that this value is strictly for the diatomic molecule $\ce{OH}$ in gas phase and is determined as the standard enthalpy change for the fission process

$$\ce{O-H → O + H}.$$

#### References

1. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data*, 97th ed.; Taylor & Francis Group (CRC Press): Boca Raton, FL, **2016**. ISBN 978-1-4987-5429-3.
2. Ruscic, B.; Feller, D.; Peterson, K. A. Active Thermochemical Tables: Dissociation Energies of Several Homonuclear First-Row Diatomics and Related Thermochemical Values. *Theor Chem Acc* **2014**, 133 (1), 1415. DOI: [10.1007/s00214-013-1415-z](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00214-013-1415-z).